# Python: List of lists with condition between arrays and no for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3 big arrays (order of millions of elements) x , v1 , v2. The arrays x and v1 have the same size and different to the size of v2. The arrays v1 and v2 will have some elements in common. I want to produce a list of lists with elements from x, given a condition between the arrays v1 and v2: every coincidence of v1 and v2 incorporates the element x to the list, having as many final members as elements in the array v2.
Up to now, I have worked this and it does exactly what I want:

```
list_foo = []    
for k in range( 0 , N ): # N = len(v2) 
    list_foo.append( x[ v1 == v2[k] ] )
```

Problem: The presence of the for loop seems to be problematic with 
         a nice python practice and the big sizes of the arrays involved. This section of code took about 1.5 seconds on my machine (MacOsX 10.8, python 2) having arrays of 250,000 elements

Question: Is there a better way to do this?

Second try: I have tried the list comprehension practice:

```
list_foo = [ [goo] for goo in x if (v1 == v2) ]
```

The problem I have up to this point is that I do not how to "solve" the index 
dependence at the comparison point `v1 == v2[k]` in the for loop to adapt it in the list comprehension method.

**Edit**

Following suggestions involving list comprehension and numpy I have made a test to compare. I have verified the 3 sections of code produce the desired output.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

# testing for loop
list_foo_for = []
start_time_for = timeit.default_timer()
for k in range( 0 , len(v2) ):
    list_foo_for.append( x[ v1 == v2[k] ] )
elapsed_for = timeit.default_timer() - start_time_for

# testing list comprehension
start_time_comp = timeit.default_timer()
list_foo_comp = [ x[ v1 == v2[k] ] for k in range(0,len(v2))]
elapsed_comp = timeit.default_timer() - start_time_comp

# testing numpy help
start_time_np = timeit.default_timer()
list_foo_np = [ x[k] for k in np.array([v1 == v for v in v2])]
elapsed_np = timeit.default_timer() - start_time_np
```

[image: Comparison of 3 suggestions...]

I can see that the incorporation of numpy in the process is one order of magnitude bigger in time execution. In the limit of low number of elements of the array 
there is no difference in comparison to the for loop. When the arrays are much bigger I can see an increase in time execution of about 10%, so up to now I am going to use the list comprehension suggestion.

Comment: Is `N` above `len(v2)`?

Comment: A simple input to your program as well as the expected output for that would be good.

Comment: Do you require that `list_foo` be a list of arrays (like your output)? If so, then it necessarily must be jagged, which means your implementation is going to be close to optimal (unless you can e.g. sort `v1` to speed up comparison).

Comment: The second try seems a bit strange. You say that `v1` and `v2` are of different sizes. Then `v1 == v2` should always evaluate to `False`. `list_foo` will always be an `empty list`.

Comment: @LakshayGarg: I think the second snippet is known to be wrong/incomplete. The questioner is asking how to introduce into it some change that makes it look at only one index of `v2` (the correct one, called `k` in the first snippet).

Comment: Is the first snippet actually what you really want? Have you tested it? To me it looks that you are indexing `x` with a boolean (comparition of entire `v1` array with an element in `v2`, which is probably `False`).

Comment: @skyking The question is tagged `numpy`. `x`, `v1`, `v2` are numpy arrays. They can be indexed using booleans

Comment: Can either `v1` or `v2` have duplicate elements within themselves? What are their typical shapes?

Comment: @Lakshay OK, it still looks odd to me, but I've no experience in `numpy`. Does it actually do what was intended?

Comment: @skyking It's not clear from the question but yes it does not always evaluate to false

Comment: I have edited the question to include some points exposed in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for `enumerate`.

```
list_foo = [ [goo] for j, goo in enumerate(x) if (v1[j] == v2[j]) ]
```

Then of course you may have to modify it according to what you really want, the above code will result in a list of lists (each containing one of the elements in `x`) for which the condition is true.

You could also use list comprehention (ie `t[x[ v1 == v2[k] ] for k in range(0,N)]`) to be equivalent of the loop. However question is whether it will be a significant speed improvement or not, you have to test.

Comment: `@skyking` Your suggestion about the list comprehension equivalence for my loop is the closest in spirit to my question. From the tests it seems is the optimal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm able to understand from your question is that you want to accomplish what the first function does using a list comprehension. If that is what you meant then here goes.

```
from numpy import *

x = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
v1 = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
v2 = array([4, 1, 6, 5])

list_foo = [x[j] for j in array([v1 == v for v in v2])]
```

It gives you a list of numpy arrays, same as your first function.